# 2010 Grand Caravan smoke coming from the hood

Tags: troubleshooting, dodge, grand-caravan

I have a 2010 Grand Caravan, I noticed smoke coming out of the hood so I brought it to a dealer to get it fixed. They said it's the intake or they change the gasket, after they fixed it I drove my car again and after a while it started smoking again. Help me please...

Comment: What gasket did they change?  I have almost that same car, and I had to replace the rear valve cover gasket because it was leaking and creating a strong burning oil smell in the cabin.  Does the smoke smell like oil, or is it more like steam from water/antifreeze?

Comment: Where is the smoke coming from?  Does it come from your exhaust pipe?

Comment: they said its the intake

Comment: The smoke is coming out of the intake of your car while it is running?